# Redirect directory to subdomain cpanel

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Alright I have already contacted BlueHost Support and they couldn't figure out how to fix this issue.  I've also tried to use cpanels 301 permanent redirect but that doesn't work so I decided to give it a whirl on here.

I host with BlueHost.com if you haven't caught that by now.  The file structure is as follows:

**public_html/

directory1/subdomaindirectory

directory2

directory3**

I have my main website in my root (public_html).  Then I have to create new directories and assign the url to that directory.  So essentially if you typed in www.maindomain.com/directory1 it would show the website in the directory.  I would like to modify the .htaccess to redirect that to it's original domain so www.maindomain.com/directory1 would go to www.directory1.com

The same for subdomains.  I created subdomain.directory1.com and pointed it to public_html/directory1/subdomaindirectory and if you go to www.directory1.com/subdomain it pulls up the site.

I realize theoretically it's the same thing but it bugs me that you are able to pull up a website like that.

Is there anyway to modify the .htaccess to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In.htaccess you could do it like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gorbox
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.gorbox.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^support$ http://support.gorbox.com [L,R=301]
```

Put this in the `.htaccess` file that resides within the root folder of `www.gorbox.com`

Comment: I might be doing it wrong but here is the actual web address so you can help me put this in correctly.  www.gorbox.com/support should redirect to support.gorbox.com  --- The file structure is public_html/gorbox/support

Comment: It still goes to www.gorbox.com/support/  --- I put this in the .htaccess located in public_html/gorbox

Comment: I've added a `RewriteBase`. If this doesn't work then it must be another rule with your file that os conflicting with it.

Comment: Dang that didn't work either.  That's the only thing in that .htaccess file too.

Comment: If you think of anything else please let me know :)  Thanks for attempting to help!